# how to select more than one foreign key in a mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, foreign-keys, subquery

So I want to insert a new column into a table using mysql.

Here is an example of a insert-into function from w3schools

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, Country)
SELECT SupplierName, Country FROM Suppliers
WHERE Country='Germany';
```

I've attempted to modified it a bit in order to basically select and insert specific integer values from two other tables. I've tried a couple different ways without luck. Here's what I'm roughly trying to do:

```
INSERT INTO table0 (integerVar1, integerVar2, booleanVar1)
SELECT int1 FROM table1 WHERE aString = "something",
       int2 FROM table2 WHERE bString = "otherthing",
       0;
```

The code above isn't valid syntax. What would I have to adjust to make the selection? Or would I have to try something completely different? Thank you very much.

Comment: Use the English language to describe what you want to do. "Basically" and "roughly" do not magically communicate what you want or make it ok to not say what you want. Also give the SQL defining the tables. Also always give the exact error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have each in a sub-select like below:

```
INSERT INTO table0 (integerVar1, integerVar2, booleanVar1)
SELECT (SELECT int1 FROM table1 WHERE aString = 'something'),
       (SELECT int2 FROM table2 WHERE bString = 'otherthing'),
       0;
```

However, keep in mind that if you have more than one value returned by the sub-select, it will not work.

This will be safer to use:

```
INSERT INTO table0 (integerVar1, integerVar2, booleanVar1)
SELECT (SELECT int1 FROM table1 WHERE aString = 'something' LIMIT 1),
       (SELECT int2 FROM table2 WHERE bString = 'otherthing' LIMIT 1),
       0;
```

Comment: Good point about multiple matches, although, if the query returns multiple rows where the OP expects one, I'd say that is something that should be solved at the design level.

Answer (score 3):

The following would work for you as long as the sub queries only returned one row ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18210/1/0)):

```
INSERT INTO table0 (integerVar1, integerVar2, booleanVar1)
SELECT (SELECT int1 FROM table1 WHERE aString = "something") AS integerVar1,
       (SELECT int2 FROM table2 WHERE bString = "otherthing") AS integerVar2, 0
```

If they have the potential of returning more than one row, then you should narrow down the results via a more detailed where clause or using a limit clause.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers show how you can use subqueries to retrieve the required values. I would add that since you [seem to] expect a single match for each string, you could also use the `INSERT...VALUES` syntax instead of `INSERT...SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO table0 (integerVar1, integerVar2, booleanVar1)
VALUES
(
  (SELECT int1 FROM table1 WHERE aString = 'something'),
  (SELECT int2 FROM table2 WHERE bString = 'otherthing'),
  0
);
```

but that would be nothing more than just a syntactical variation (in this particular case).

What I would actually like to draw your attention to is that each of the two subqueries might return an empty set and thus evaluate as a scalar NULL. Would you still like to insert the row if either or both of the references were NULL?

If you would prefer the query not to insert a row in such a case, you could consider this approach instead:

```
INSERT INTO table0 (integerVar1, integerVar2, booleanVar1)
SELECT
  t1.int1, t2.int2, 0
FROM
  (SELECT int1 FROM table1 WHERE aString = 'something') AS t1
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT int2 FROM table2 WHERE bString = 'otherthing') AS t2
;
```

If *either* of the subqueries does not return a row, the cross join of the two sets would be empty and the INSERT, therefore, would not insert any row into `table0`.